# Change dot to comma

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I did a new field to prices on functions to woocommerce.
That field is printing on my database with DOT and i want to print with COMMA.

Wrong: R$ 40.00
Correct: R$ 40,00

```
function addSlubField() {
    global $post;
$args = array(
  'label' => 'Slub Price', // Text in Label
  'label' => __('Slub Price', 'woocommerce') ,
  'placeholder' => 'Slub Price',
  'class' => 'short',
  'style' => '',
  'wrapper_class' => '',
  'value'=>get_post_meta($post->ID,'slub_price',true),
  'id' => 'slub_price', // required
  'name' => 'slub_price', //name will set from id if empty
  'type' => 'number',
  'desc_tip' => '',
  'data_type' => '',
  'custom_attributes' => array('step'=>'0.01'), // array of attributes
  'description' => ''
);
woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'addSlubField',1);

add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_slub_field' );
function save_slub_field( $post_id ) {

  $custom_field_value = isset( $_POST['slub_price'] ) ? $_POST['slub_price'] : '';

  $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
  $product->update_meta_data( 'slub_price', $custom_field_value );
  $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Don't change your database schema. The databases use periods, not commas, as decimal separators, and changing it in your database will mess things up. Instead, change how it's printing out by (I think) changing your PHP locale or using `number_format`

Comment: If you already have commas as a separator in your Woocommerce Currency setting, you could print using wc_price( $slub_price);